Ros2 control joint commands not reflecting in Gazebo
I have a ros2-control controller (custom, but basically a souped-up DiffDriveController for the purpose of this question) that I know is sending nonzero commands to velocity and position command interfaces of my drive/steering joints. These drive motors are simulated in Gazebo, and the controllers have claimed the relevant joints. However, none of the commands I'm sending are reflected in either Gazebo or rviz. The only hint I have is a warning, which is pasted below.
I am expecting Gazebo to mirror the commanded joint values, but obviously it's not. I've also attached the gazebo topic list, because my intuition says something is missing, but I've had a hard time figuring out exactly what that might be.
The important part of the log is:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990220826] [gz_ros_control.resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990454825] [gz_ros_control.resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'GazeboSimSystem'
[gazebo-2] [WARN] [1732000433.990506081] [gz_ros_control.resource_manager]: Importing state interfaces for the hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' returned no state interfaces.
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990710353] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990725623] [gz_ros_control]: System Successfully configured!

Full log (a lot of irrelevant information, but maybe something here will help)
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/lunabot/.ros/log/2024-11-19-02-13-50-813451-lunabot-jazzy-ltvm-39783
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [39787]
[INFO] [gazebo-2]: process started with pid [39788]
[INFO] [create-3]: process started with pid [39789]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-4]: process started with pid [39790]
[INFO] [rviz2-5]: process started with pid [39791]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [39793]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [39794]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1732000431.170906698] [robot_state_publisher]: Robot initialized
[create-3] [INFO] [1732000431.173397487] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[rviz2-5] MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
[rviz2-5] glx: failed to create drisw screen
[rviz2-5] MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
[rviz2-5] glx: failed to create drisw screen
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1732000431.593636938] [spawner_joint_broadcast]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1732000431.617613010] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1732000431.617998082] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1732000431.624365878] [spawner_drive_ctrl]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1732000431.673364433] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[gazebo-2] MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
[gazebo-2] glx: failed to create drisw screen
[create-3] [INFO] [1732000431.809100034] [ros_gz_sim]: Entity creation successfull.
[INFO] [create-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 39789]
[parameter_bridge-4] [INFO] [1732000432.208820782] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/clock (gz.msgs.Clock) -> /clock (rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock)] (Lazy 0)
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.932314333] [gz_ros_control]: Loading controller_manager
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.969905206] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '/robot_description' topic for robot description.
[gazebo-2] [WARN] [1732000433.970255362] [gz_ros_control]: Waiting RM to load and initialize hardware...
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.981375566] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989416098] [gz_ros_control]: The position_proportional_gain has been set to: 0.1
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989592248] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: steer_fl
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989602296] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989608498] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989623777] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989631501] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989638064] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989643484] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989666427] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: steer_fr
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989689219] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989695091] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989701452] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989708816] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989714336] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989720038] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989738653] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: steer_bl
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989744944] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989751236] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989757608] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989764301] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989773117] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989778727] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989805848] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: steer_br
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989812100] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989817309] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989822690] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989827969] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989833540] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989838810] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989851905] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: drive_fl
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989857615] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989863086] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989868566] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989874136] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989879396] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989884676] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989899264] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: drive_fr
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989905615] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989910775] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989942615] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989950860] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989955820] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989960758] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989973182] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: drive_bl
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989979063] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989984323] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989989984] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.989995494] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990000904] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990005753] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990017505] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: drive_br
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990023206] [gz_ros_control]:  State:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990028886] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990033986] [gz_ros_control]:       position
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990039296] [gz_ros_control]:       effort
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990044757] [gz_ros_control]:  Command:
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990050306] [gz_ros_control]:       velocity
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990220826] [gz_ros_control.resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990454825] [gz_ros_control.resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'GazeboSimSystem'
[gazebo-2] [WARN] [1732000433.990506081] [gz_ros_control.resource_manager]: Importing state interfaces for the hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' returned no state interfaces.
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990710353] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990725623] [gz_ros_control]: System Successfully configured!
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990755748] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'GazeboSimSystem'
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990775786] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990781066] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'GazeboSimSystem'
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000433.990821552] [controller_manager]: Resource Manager has been successfully initialized. Starting Controller Manager services...
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.105942271] [controller_manager]: Loading controller : 'joint_broadcast' of type 'joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster'
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.106026588] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_broadcast'
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.115095258] [controller_manager]: Controller 'joint_broadcast' node arguments: --ros-args --params-file /home/lunabot/git/Lunabotics-WPI-25/ros2_ws/src/luna_urdf/luna_control/controllers.yaml --param use_sim_time:=true 
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1732000434.146658341] [spawner_joint_broadcast]: Loaded joint_broadcast
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.239427132] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller: 'joint_broadcast'
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.240712301] [joint_broadcast]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.269976635] [controller_manager]: Loading controller : 'drive_ctrl' of type 'luna_control/LunaController'
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.270100898] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'drive_ctrl'
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.283178632] [controller_manager]: Controller 'drive_ctrl' node arguments: --ros-args --params-file /home/lunabot/git/Lunabotics-WPI-25/ros2_ws/src/luna_urdf/luna_control/controllers.yaml --param use_sim_time:=true 
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000434.329971603] [controller_manager]: Activating controllers: [ joint_broadcast ]
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1732000434.331001714] [spawner_drive_ctrl]: Loaded drive_ctrl
[gazebo-2] [WARN] [1732000436.014495404] [gz_ros_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.05 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.153400135] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller: 'drive_ctrl'
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1732000436.154907991] [spawner_joint_broadcast]: Configured and activated joint_broadcast
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.307581431] [controller_manager]: Activating controllers: [ drive_ctrl ]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 39793]
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.502451154] [drive_ctrl]: Linear command is 0.000000
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.502945301] [drive_ctrl]: Commanded wheel_lb velocity: 0.000000
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.502978303] [drive_ctrl]: sanity check: wheels_per_side = 1
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1732000436.503877658] [spawner_drive_ctrl]: Configured and activated drive_ctrl
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.722376163] [drive_ctrl]: Linear command is 0.000000
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.722504875] [drive_ctrl]: Commanded wheel_lb velocity: 0.000000
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.722512087] [drive_ctrl]: sanity check: wheels_per_side = 1
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 39794]
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.949600624] [drive_ctrl]: Linear command is 0.000000
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.949779400] [drive_ctrl]: Commanded wheel_lb velocity: 0.000000
[gazebo-2] [INFO] [1732000436.949788848] [drive_ctrl]: sanity check: wheels_per_side = 1


Gazebo topic list: (isn't there supposed to be some model information here? the model is spawned)
$ gz topic -l
/clock
/gazebo/resource_paths
/gui/camera/pose
/gui/currently_tracked
/gui/track
/stats
/world/empty/clock
/world/empty/dynamic_pose/info
/world/empty/pose/info
/world/empty/scene/deletion
/world/empty/scene/info
/world/empty/state
/world/empty/stats
/world/empty/light_config
/world/empty/material_color


Which gazebo version and ROS distro are you using? Do the demos work?

Regarding returned no state interfaces, this might be a bug and misleading info. Fixed here
